# Поменять получателя в html

Tags: css3, html5

Добрый вечер помогите разобраться в работе анкеты.
http://liquidrubber.by/kontakty/ - оригинал
http://s419600.smrtp.ru/contacts/ - мой(можете туда не заходить он просто переведён на хорватский)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно поменять почту на которую приходит сообщение не могу найти где и куда копать.
Чтоб вам не бегать сейчас код этого блока сюда вставлю.

```
<div class="form-id-2">
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f272-p32-o1" lang="ru-RU" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response" role="alert">Спасибо за Ваше сообщение. Оно успешно отправлено.</div>
<form action="/kontakty/#wpcf7-f272-p32-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form sent" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="272">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.1.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="ru_RU">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f272-p32-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="32">
<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="03AGdBq271njTn1Z6IB-HE6euBAp_03sguQHguZ91eUNkOkaZvmj2CIGqDW7KaGoWYD5LNBeIJJKIDeoMIF_AZs5lcSt9IhX7nwZxhJU4bTuPQd1Rlt3wXHheCzV21_Lg9BflZtXypMLjexIksm9xdYc6TudQ--13TRnTlGsXhqoHlgbUnxUfIlcYmBkat6rqj9ulTeHcMREk3odm7IDkpNmFjxJMaZeAyI4l2PN9SRlJfEhIkePab7QDNcMXsZQx8njk431RoNylL38XEktn8s8dhFcgE-1KTp3Bf2jWflt6SCGEVpO9a7876HMWLVWwLVYfVFhKOdXbvJsetd-2EqYKvcOidPfZfGPAbS-FUo2MqKhpUuAO0NWCkeVN9k8vka3MvcebYLA7E7kJjRfiwklFZE4fROFvO3nbc7_Juv3jfV3P92Bmy0JwfZNzY-Z97_dgIZLcgZHQ8">
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden-anim" data-vp-add-class="visible animated fadeInUp">
<label for="Name"> Имя* </label><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap user-name"><input type="text" name="user-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="Name" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваше имя"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden-anim" data-vp-add-class="visible animated fadeInUp">
<label for="organization"> Организация </label><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap user-organization"><input type="text" name="user-organization" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control" id="organization" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваша Организация"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden-anim" data-vp-add-class="visible animated fadeInUp">
<label for="phone"> Телефон </label><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap user-phone"><input type="text" name="user-phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="phone" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваш телефон"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden-anim" data-vp-add-class="visible animated fadeInUp">
<label for="phone"> Email* </label><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap user-email"><input type="text" name="user-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Ваш email"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden-anim" data-vp-add-class="visible animated fadeInUp">
<label for="text"> Какой вопрос Вас интересует? </label><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap user-message"><textarea name="user-message" cols="40" rows="3" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea form-control" id="text" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="user-geolocation" value="Россия, Краснодарский край, undefined" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden" id="geolocation">
<p><input type="submit" value="Получить консультацию" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-black"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;" role="alert">Спасибо за Ваше сообщение. Оно успешно отправлено.</div></form></div></div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: отправляет сообщение сервер, как я понимаю - это к html имеет мало отношения

Comment: а где может прописана почта ?

Comment: в коде, который выполняется на сервере.

Comment: можно как то название его узнать, всё таки ему html должен передать что было написано?

Comment: я не знаю, что у вас там на сервере -что-то самописное или стандартный wp. например, на каком языке написано, есть ли файл  или таблица БД для настроек и тд и тп. На ваш вопрос  невозможно ответить по этой информации

Comment: Что вам предоставить, что бы вы могли помочь?

Comment: я могу дать доступ к хостингу

Comment: нет, это не ко мне.

Comment: жаль( А ещё вопрос файл он где должен именно лежать именно на хостинге или в папки странницы?

Comment: зависит от структуры сайта. в любом месте

Comment: хм.. как же быть

Comment: обратиться в службу поддержки хостинга; попробовать разобраться; найти того, кто будет разбираться,

Comment: Хорошо спасибо тебе за советы!